# How to Escape dot(.) In a substitution variable

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

I have a variable called `ERROR_DETAIL` and inside my file `file.sql` I have this line:

```
SELECT 'error detail : &ERROR_DETAIL ' FROM DUAL;
```

Once executed sqlplus complains with  the following error when the variable `ERROR_DETAIL` contains for example `'the field x.y is mandatory'`:

> ```
> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> ```

I know about the issue with `x.y` (treated as table.column).

I tried to use double quotes, but I get an *invalid identifier* error

Also I can't `set define off`.

This is the error I receive with the script I have:

[image: Error message in script]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT q'{error detail : &ERROR_DETAIL }' FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> SELECT 'error detail : ' || &ERROR_DETAIL from dual;
Enter value for error_detail: 'the field x.y is mandatory'
old   1: SELECT 'error detail : ' || &ERROR_DETAIL from dual
new   1: SELECT 'error detail : ' || 'the field x.y is mandatory'  from dual

'ERRORDETAIL:'||'THEFIELDX.YISMANDATORY'
-----------------------------------------
error detail : the field x.y is mandatory

SQL>
```